# Is feature independence needed when training a neural network with the Cross-Entropy Method?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, optimization, cross-entropy

I'm using the Cross-Entropy Method (CEM) [1] [2] to train a neural network (NN) for use in reinforcement learning.

I get poor performance when my elite sample size gets larger than a couple samples, even if I increase the total number of samples as to keep the elite proportion low.  I'm wondering if the problem is that my NN features are correlated/colinear.  Wouldn't that cause my NN weights to be unstable?  If my weights are unstable, wouldn't averaging over the elite sample be bad?

For example, two sets of near-optimal NN weights could be far away from each other in parameter space, so the averaging that's done in the CEM would result in new weights being chosen in a region that's not close to either optimal region.

[1] http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/0ff1/88986e48d17fc4b59e6c4c00681794c9fd08.pdf

[2] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01842.pdf

Comment: Colinearity is indeed an issue for NN, as it can lead to overfitting. Also, it could make your model too sensitive for changes in data, as a change in one variable can greatly affect its colinear part.